# Difference between "<%=" and "<%" when mixing ruby with html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Rails, and i'm doing a exercise which i have to mix some html with ruby in a view file.

What is the main difference between " <%= #code %> " and " <% #code %>  ", when coding ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= something which you would like to have displayed in your view %>
<% something you would like to have hidden, 
(or something which doesn't display anything in the view) such as a
 conditional statement %>

<% if @post.nil? %>
    <%= render "nilNotify" %>
<% else %>
    <%= @post.content %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<%= 1 + 2 %>` will evaluate AND display the result.
In this case, you should see 3 in your view.

`<% 1 + 2 %>` will evaluate but will not display the result in the view. In this case, you will not see 3 in your view.

Comment: And you can add stuff to be displayed even with `<%` by using `concat`.